# How to draw canvas elements in the right positions?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using javascript to draw a rectangle around DOM elements in a website.

The problem is that the rectangles are drawn in the wrong positions.

I know that canvas, work like a real canvas so you have to "predraw" everything before filling the canvas, otherwise the elements will be on top of each other, in the orders you drew them.

That's why I'm defining canvas, and context outside of the loop.

This is my code:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5;

    //Set canvas width/height
    canvas.style.width='100%';
    canvas.style.height='100%';

    //Set canvas drawing area width/height
    canvas.width = document.width;
    canvas.height = document.height;

    //Position canvas
    canvas.style.position='absolute';
    canvas.style.left=0;
    canvas.style.top=0;
    canvas.style.zIndex=100000;
    canvas.style.pointerEvents='none'; //Make sure you can click 'through' the canvas
    document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element


var listingsRect = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.rc'), function(e) {
        return e.getBoundingClientRect();
    });
listingsRect.forEach(function(listingRect) {
    var x = listingRect.left;
    var y = listingRect.top;
    var width = listingRect.width;
    var height = listingRect.height;

    //Draw rectangle
    context.rect(x, y, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fill();
});
```

However, when I change 
`canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` respectively, then canvas draws the rectangles in the right positions, however it only draws them in the visible area of the website (obviously).

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?

Here's a JS bin:

http://jsbin.com/elUToGO/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x,y in context.rect(x,y,width,height) **are relative to the canvas element not to the browser window.**

So if your canvas element is absolutely positioned at 50,75 and you want a rect at window position 110,125 you would draw your rect like this:

```
context.rect( 110-50, 125-75, width, height );
```

A few other things:

If you set the canvas element width/height and then position absolutely, you don't need canvas.style.width/height.

document.width/height are deprecated (& not supported in IE) . Use this instead:

```
//Set canvas drawing area width/height
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

When setting style.left/top, you might want to pass a string with "px" in case you later set >0.

```
canvas.style.left="0px";
canvas.style.top="0px";
```

.pointerEvents='none' is supported in most browsers (but not in IE<11)

Comment: I'm not concerned right now about cross browser compatibility because I'm using a headless browser to run this scripts, so as long as they work in PhantomJS I'm ok with that, but thanks for the heads up! 

On the other hand, what if my viewport is not large enough to see the whole webpage? if document.width/height are deprecated how am I going to be able to draw a rectangle around every element JS finds, including the ones that are not visible.

Comment: You can use window.innerWidth instead of document.width to get the viewport width including any scrollbar. You can absolutely position the canvas even if its outside the viewport.  Hint: if you're resizing, any change in canvas.width/height will clear the canvas so you will have to redraw the rect after resizing.  Hint: don't use css to resize the canvas as the pixels will be "stretched" causing image distortion (not a problem if you're just drawing a single-color rect--but drawings/images will distort.